# How to get the value of attributes

Tags: php, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Having difficulties getting all the attributes of tags starting with `<div id="test_num...">` from a page using Selenium Webdriver. Basically, I need to get all the values of ids that contain `"test_num"` from the following code

```
<body> 
<div id="test_num_1" .....></div>     
<div id="test_num_2" .....></div>
<div id="test_num_3" .....></div>
<div id="test_num_4" .....></div>
</body>
```

I have tried the following without any luck:

```
$allvalues=$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('//*
    [contains(@id,'test_num')]'));
```

Also tried using css-selector which didn't help.

Appreciate if somebody can point me to any information.

Comment: "Did not help" - what do you mean? Any errors? What have you got as the `$allvalues` value?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of the **`quotes`**. Try the following :

```
$allvalues=$driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::xpath("//div[contains(@id,'test_num_')]"));
```